# Unable to get serviceWorkerRegistration

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) ,to make Push notification on Google Chrome by using GCM. My problem is I'm unable to complete the operation! i have no idea why.

In subscribe function, it breaks out the function whenever it tries to execute

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {  
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()  
        .then(function(subscription) { 
            // ...
        };
});
```

It has no console error and no console warning and it doesn't enter the catch! Here is what I did:

```js
function subscribe() {  

  var pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-button');  
  pushButton.disabled = true;

  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {  
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()  
      .then(function(subscription) {  

        // The subscription was successful
        isPushEnabled = true;  
        pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messages';  
        pushButton.disabled = false;
        console.log("sending sub");
        sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
        // TODO: Send the subscription.endpoint to your server
        // and save it to send a push message at a later date
        return sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);  
      })  
      .catch(function(e) {  
        if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {  
          // The user denied the notification permission which
          // means we failed to subscribe and the user will need
          // to manually change the notification permission to
          // subscribe to push messages
          console.warn('Permission for Notifications was denied');  
          pushButton.disabled = true;  
        } else {  
          // A problem occurred with the subscription; common reasons
          // include network errors, and lacking gcm_sender_id and/or
          // gcm_user_visible_only in the manifest.
          console.error('Unable to subscribe to push.', e);  
          pushButton.disabled = false;  
          pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messages';  
        }  
      });  
  });  
}
```

Comment: Please try registering your service worker first as this is the first step in using it. This [GitHub post](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md) might help to better understand service workers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that did work for me is the 'getRegistration' method, used as the following code

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/Workers/').then( r => subscribe( r ) );
```

where '/Workers/' is the path where the ServiceWorker.js is